# How to issue a SOAP request in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to issue a SOAP request in PHP. I have my service URL, and when I check it in SOAP UI, I can see the following

```
<application xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">
   <doc xml:lang="en" title="https://someurl.com"/>
   <resources base="https://someurl.com">
      <resource path="sdk/user/session/logon/" id="Logon">
         <doc xml:lang="en" title="Logon"/>
         <param name="ApiKey" type="xs:string" required="false" default="" style="query" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
         <param name="ApiSecret" type="xs:string" required="false" default="" style="query" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
         <method name="POST" id="Logon">
            <doc xml:lang="en" title="Logon"/>
            <request>
               <param name="method" type="xs:string" required="true" default="" style="query" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
               <representation mediaType="text/xml"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            </request>
            <response status="404 500">
               <representation mediaType="text/html; charset=utf-8" element="html"/>
            </response>
            <response status="">
               <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
               <representation mediaType="text/xml"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            </response>
            <response status="500">
               <representation mediaType="application/vnd.marg.bcsocial.result-v1.9+json; charset=utf-8" element="log:Fault" xmlns:log="https://someurl.com/sdk/user/session/logon"/>
               <representation mediaType="application/vnd.marg.bcsocial.result-v1.9+xml; charset=utf-8" element="web:Result_1" xmlns:web="https://someurl.com/Sdk/WebService"/>
            </response>
            <response status="200">
               <representation mediaType="application/vnd.marg.bcsocial.api.index.options.list-v2.6+xml; charset=utf-8" element="web:ListOfApiIndexOptions_4" xmlns:web="https://someurl.com/Sdk/WebService"/>
               <representation mediaType="" element="data"/>
            </response>
         </method>
      </resource>
   </resources>
</application>
```

So I am trying to use this to log on.  At the moment, I am trying something like the following

```
public function updateApi(){
    $service_url = 'https://someurl.com/sdk/user/session/logon';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
        "ApiKey" => 'somekey',
        "ApiSecret" => 'somesecret',
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($curl_response);
}
```

However, I always receive a fault response that the login has failed.  Do I have to call the logon method or something?
Really just looking for some advice as to whether I am doing things correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Docs for the service you are trying to hit might have explanation of their RESTful services and how to use it. Can you share which API you are trying to hit? Perhaps someone has written wrappers that you could use to simplify your work.

Comment: Unfortunately its a private API, docs are not available unless you log in.  Docs only show very basic notes.  I have searched and there are no wrappers anywhere.

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing the required `method` parameter in your request?

Comment: Try to send your curl_post_data variable as a URL Encoded string. like urlencode('ApiKey=somekey&ApiSecret=somesecret') and secondly try to set the content-type of your request to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded''

Answer (score 7):

You don't set the `Content-Type` header telling the format of the content you posted:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

Otherwise, from php5 upwards, the usage of `http_build_query` is recommended:

```
$curl_post_data = array(
    "ApiKey" => 'somekey',
    "ApiSecret" => 'somesecret',
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            http_build_query($curl_post_data));
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 6):

According the XML you should try to send your curl_post_data variable as a URL Encoded string. like `urlencode('ApiKey=somekey&ApiSecret=somesecret')` and secondly try to set the content-type of your request to '`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`'

Answer (score 6):

```
$service_url = 'https://someurl.com/sdk/user/session/logon';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$headers = ["Content-Type: application/json"];  // or other supported media type
$curl_post_data = array(
    "ApiKey" => 'somekey',
    "ApiSecret" => 'somesecret',
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```